# How can I see all the tags in "Tech you want to work with"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In "Edit Profile and Settings", under the "Job Preferences" section there is a location to put "tech you want to work with".  I have several different tags (8+) in here but can only see 3-4 of them at a time.
As near as I can tell there's no way to scroll to view the others.

[image: Tech you want to work with showing 3 tags only]

If I inspect this section in the browser console there are several `span`s listing the other tech I've typed in - but they're not visible until I remove one of these visible ones.

Comment: I'm able to duplicate this bug.  The workaround to this bug is to

Comment: `$(".tag-editor.multi-line").height(300)` as a quick one-off 'fix'.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but you can use the arrow keys to make the other tags visible.

Comment: Confirmed arrow keys do work - although down opens a separate dialog to choose variations of the same tag.

Comment: Guess we'll need to add an `overflow-y:scroll` on the div tag, or something like that. Looking...

Answer (score 1):

You should now be able to vertically scroll those tag lists, if necessary:

[image]